# PHP svn_diff error

Tags: php, apache, svn

When executing svd_diff the page just shows "No data received Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

I'm trying to execute this:

```
$diff = svn_diff($this->folder, $this->from_revision, $this->folder, $this->to_revision ? $this->to_revision : SVN_REVISION_HEAD);
```

Apache error.log shows:

```
[Fri Jun 20 11:31:13.772711 2014] [core:notice] [pid 21314] AH00051: child pid 21319 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

I'm using Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu) with PHP Version 5.5.13-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
 
I have svn and php5-svn installed

This is happening since I change from Ubuntu 12 to 14

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

This code might help you

```
<?php
list($diff, $errors) = svn_diff(
    'http://www.example.com/svnroot/trunk/foo', SVN_REVISION_HEAD,
    'http://www.example.com/svnroot/branches/dev/foo', SVN_REVISION_HEAD
);
if (!$diff) exit;
$contents = '';
while (!feof($diff)) {
  $contents .= fread($diff, 8192);
}
fclose($diff);
fclose($errors);
var_dump($contents);
?>
```

Comment: exactly the same as before